# Trying to split string, but I have issues related to encoding

Tags: python-3.x

I want to split a string , in two base on the last space in the string.

Example:

```
    full_text = "0.808 um"
    value, unit = full_text.rsplit(" ")
```

This should have worked bu I get the error:

```
 ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

So I printed, on what happens on split:

```
['0.808\xa0um']
```

In my example the string is static, but in reality I receive them from a database, and I don't know when a space is space or not.

I want to maintain the encoding for characters (not space) received, but also want to split.

Comment: In your example you are trying to split a different string, you assign the value to full_stext but use spec_full_value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would simply need to expect more and different kinds of whitespace to split by. In your case you're dealing with a no-break space. The regular expression `\s` would match it and a few other kinds of whitespace:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'\s', '0.808\xa0um')
['0.808', 'um']
```